# read email from an email acount on an exchange server through java mail api

Tags: java, email, exchange-server

I  am trying to access an exchange server to **read** emails from a specific acount using  JAVA mail.

I can access gmail with something like

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(host, username, password);
```

but since I am using exchange I dont have pop3, 
I only have server name : mysrv ,domain name: MYDOMIAN and a mailbox : my@mail.co.il.

So what is the correct way to connect to exchange?

Comment: I thought they have IMAP support.  Looks like https://github.com/alexguev/exjello may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect(host, username, password);
```

Comment: how do i figure out what the right host is for imaps?  can I see it from microsoft outlook ?

Comment: the name of the exchange. your domain say mail-exch@mail.com

Comment: imaps didnt work, imap did.  also the ip of the server didnt work as host, only the server name.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP4 won't give you contacts/appointments/tasks/etc.
You can use [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx), Outlook Object Model (assuming you have Outlook installed and a profile configured to talk to a particular mailbox) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object(RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox etc.)